# Recorriendo matrices eficientemente (Caché)

Tags: c#, optimización, manejo-de-memoria, rendimiento

Alguna idea sobre un algoritmo que permita, para la gran mayoria de tamaños de matriz, de manera que el miss rate en caché sea minimo.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español @mgltorsa. Tu pregunta es muy amplia, sería mejor si mostraras tu código para analizarlo y tratar de optimizarlo. En C#, la máquina virtual normalmente mantiene los objetos en memoria RAM por lo que dificilmente estarás accediendo a caché, a menos que utilices estructuras en lugar de objetos (y renunciando a beneficios como la herencia en pos del rendimiento). Luego, hay ciertas optimizaciones que se pueden hacer en los ciclos, como separarlos si es posible, pero como te indico, depende de cada código en particular.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Como te decía en los comentarios, depende de cada código la forma en que se puede optimizar, pero vamos a ver un ejemplo genérico. Tenemos tres métodos que crean una matriz de 10000 * 10000 posiciones y la llenan, pero con variaciones:

1. Matriz de objetos
2. Matriz de estructuras

El código es el siguiente:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsolaPrueba
{
    class Program
    {
        public static int posiciones = 10000;
        public class ClasePersona{
            public int numero;
        }

        public struct EstructuraPersona {
            public int numero;
        }

        public static void PruebaClase()
        {            
            ClasePersona[,] matrizPersona = new ClasePersona[posiciones, posiciones];

            var timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            for (int x = 0; x < posiciones; x++)
            {
                ClasePersona personaXY = new ClasePersona();
                personaXY.numero = x;
                matrizPersona[x, 0] = personaXY;

                for (int y = 0; y < posiciones; y++)
                {
                    ClasePersona personaYX = new ClasePersona();
                    personaYX.numero = y;
                    matrizPersona[x, y] = personaYX;
                }
            }

            timer.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(timer.ElapsedMilliseconds);            
        }


        public static void PruebaEstructura()
        {
            EstructuraPersona[,] matrizPersona = new EstructuraPersona[posiciones, posiciones];

            var timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            for (int x = 0; x < posiciones; x++)
            {
                EstructuraPersona personaXY = new EstructuraPersona();
                personaXY.numero = x;
                matrizPersona[x, 0] = personaXY;


                for (int y = 0; y < posiciones; y++)
                {
                    EstructuraPersona personaYX = new EstructuraPersona();
                    personaYX.numero = y;
                    matrizPersona[x, y] = personaYX;
                }
            }

            timer.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(timer.ElapsedMilliseconds);            
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PruebaClase();
            PruebaEstructura();
        }
    }
}
```

Cuando lo ejecutamos (en una máquina con un I7 de 4ta generación) obtenemos estos valores:

> 9685 488

Esto se debe a que:

En el primer método se llena una matriz de objetos, estos los maneja la máquina virtual en memoria RAM, por lo que la velocidad es la mas lenta de los tres métodos. Recordemos que las instancias de clase son apuntadores a posiciones de memoria.

En el segundo método se llena una matriz de estructuras, una estructura no es un apuntador, sino que es su contenido en si, por lo que el procesador carga la matriz completa en caché y el acceso es increíblemente rápido (de 9.6 segundos a 488 milisegundos).